# Finding recurrent and transient states with first hitting probabilities (Norris exercise 1.5.1)

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory, solution-verification, markov-chains

I want to see why the following attempt won't work .

**Problem :** In a discrete time markov chain (DTMC) $(X_n)_{n\ge 0}$  with transition matrix  P and state space I , which states are recurrent and which are transient?

$$ P = 
\begin{bmatrix}
  0.50 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.50 \\ 
  0.00 & 0.50 & 0.00 & 0.50 & 0.00 \\ 
  0.00 & 0.00 & 1.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  0.00 & 0.25 & 0.25 & 0.25 & 0.25 \\ 
  0.50 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.50 \\ 
   \end{bmatrix}
$$
This DTMC has communicating classes : $\{1,5\} (closed) , \{2,4\} , \{3\}(closed)$

**The attempt :** From Norris theorem 1.5.3 ,

> The following dichotomy holds: 
>  (i) if
> $P(T_i= \inf\{n\ge 1 : X_n = i \} <\infty | X_0 = i \in I) = P_i(T_i <\infty)=1$ , then $i$ is recurrent
>
>   (ii) if
> $P(T_i= \inf\{n\ge 1 : X_n = i \} <\infty | X_0 = i \in I) = P_i(T_i  <\infty) < 1$ , then $i$ is transient 
> In particular, every state is either transient or recurrent .

Similar to Norris section 1.3 but with the difference that $T_i \ge 1 $ instead of 0 . First define $H_i = \inf\{n\ge 0 : X_n = i \}$ , so that by markov property
$$
P_i(T_i<\infty) = \sum_{j \in I} p_{ij} P_j(H_i <\infty) =  
\sum_{j \in I} p_{ij} h_{j}^{\{i\}}
$$
where we let $p_{ij}$ be the (i,j) entry of P  , and $ P_j(H_i <\infty) = h_{j}^{\{i\}} $ interpreted as $P_j(\text{hit} \; i)$ .

From Norris theorem 1.3.2  (applies only when $h_{j}^{\{i\}}$ is defined exactly as above) ,

> The vector of hitting probabilities $h^{\{i\}} = \left( h_j^{\{i\}} : j \in I  \right)^T$ is the minimal non negative solution to the system of linear equations
> $$\left\{ 
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  h_j^{\{i\}} = 1 & \text{for j = i}\\
>  h_j^{\{i\}} = \sum_{k\in I } p_{jk} h_k^{\{i\}} & \text{for j $\neq$ i}\\
> \end{array}\right.
> $$
>
>  ( Minimality means that if $x = (x_j : j \in I )$ is another solution with $x_j \ge 0$ for all j , then $x_j \ge h_j $ for all j . )

Hence , we have $P_i(T_i<\infty) = \sum_{j \in I} \sum_{k\in I } p_{ij} p_{jk} h_k^{\{i\}} \quad j \neq i  $ . So we need solve for $h^{\{i\}}$ first , theorem 1.3.2 could be represented by
$$
(I - P) h^{\{i\}}  = \mathbf{0}
$$
Let $A = (I - P | \mathbf{0} ) $ , then A has reduced row echelon form
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccccc|c}
  1.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & -1.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  0.00 & 1.00 & 0.00 & -1.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  0.00 & 0.00 & 1.00 & -2.00 & 1.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
   \end{array} \right]
$$
However , I couldn't solve for $h^{\{i\}}$ from this matrix , e.g
I obtain $h^{\{1\}} = \left( 1 , h_2^{\{1\}} , 2 h_2^{\{1\}} - 1 , h_2^{\{1\}}  , 1 \right)^T $ which I couldn't find any $h_2^{\{1\}}$ that makes it a minimal non negative solution .